# react native secureTextEntry not working on android

Tags: android, react-native, textinput

I am trying to use react-native `secureTextEntry` to hide my password and confirm password fields during registration.I'm using custom InputBox component for textInput.below is my code,

```
                <InputBox 
                error={this.state.PwordError} 
                keyboardType={'default'} 
                onChangeText={Pword =>
                    this.setState({
                        Pword
                    })
                } 
                secureTextEntry={true}
                value={this.state.Pword} 
                pHolder={"Password"} 
                color={'white'} />
            <View style={styles.spacer} />
            <InputBox 
                error={this.state.CPwordError} 
                keyboardType={'default'} 
                onChangeText={CPword =>
                    this.setState({
                        CPword
                    })
                } 
                secureTextEntry={true}
                value={this.state.CPword} 
                pHolder={"Confirm Password"} 
                color={'white'} />
```

The first textbox works fine when a password is entered it show as dots, but the confirm password field does not work. does anyone have an idea why this could occur?

This is the input box that is referred by the above code

```
            <TextInput 
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    placeholder={this.props.pHolder} 
                    placeholderTextColor={this.props.color === 'white' ? 'black':"white" } 
                    {...this.props}
                    style={this.props.color == 'white' ? styles.ReginputStyle : styles.inputStyle} 

                    />
```

i am using,

```
"react": "16.5.0",
"react-native": "0.57.1",
```

I was able to fix this by removing the `keyboardType={'default'}` code from my input component. Even though the problem is fixed i would like to know why the first `secureTextEntry` box worked while the other didn't, as both of them were identical except for the value. can any one give a reason to why this could occur,

thanks.

Comment: is InputBox your custom component ?

Comment: yes the below textInput is the textinput component thats within the `InputBox` code

Comment: I'm having the same issue. None of the answers here have helped. 
react: 18.2.0
react-native: 0.72.6
expo: 49.0.0

Testing on a physical Android device.

Answer (score 13):

multiline={true} or keyboardType={'visible-password'} prevent secureTextEntry from working.

Answer (score 12):

do `keyboardType="default"` and it will work. It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

this work for me:

`secureTextEntry works if you set autoCapitalize={'none'}.`

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30148#issuecomment-748288773

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it's happening in your code I have tried your code it's work fine in my android emulator. Rather than this, I have faced issue while updating property "color" in shadow node of type: AndroidTextInput. Because it's taking time to evaluate your

For that, I have removed this line other than this its work fine.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from "react-native";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { CPwordError: "", CPword: "", PwordError: "", Pword: "" };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <InputBox
          error={this.state.PwordError}
          keyboardType={"default"}
          onChangeText={Pword =>
            this.setState({
              Pword
            })
          }
          secureTextEntry={true}
          value={this.state.Pword}
          pHolder={"Password"}
          // color={"white"}
        />

        <InputBox
          error={this.state.CPwordError}
          keyboardType={"default"}
          onChangeText={CPword =>
            this.setState({
              CPword
            })
          }
          secureTextEntry={true}
          value={this.state.CPword}
          pHolder={"Confirm Password"}
          // color={"white"}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class InputBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          placeholder={this.props.pHolder}
          placeholderTextColor={"black"}
          {...this.props}
          style={this.props.color == "white"}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i was able to my problem by removing the `keyboardType` prop. i have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
keyboardType="default" Working Fine.
secureTextEntry={hidePassword}

  <TextInput
                        style={[styles.textInput]}
                        placeholder=""
                        secureTextEntry={hidePassword}
                        selectionColor={'#000'}
                        editable={true}
                        returnKeyType={'next'}
                        keyboardType="default"
                        autoFocus={false}
                        autoCapitalize={'characters'}
                        placeholderTextColor="rgb(153,153,153)"
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.onCurrentPassTextChange(text)}
                      >{currentPassword}</TextInput>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was adding empty `Text` before `TextInput`

**Does not work**

```
<View>
  <TextInput
      placeholder='Enter Password'
      returnKeyType="next"
      secureTextEntry={true}
  />
</View>
```

**Works**

```
<View>
  <Text></Text>
  <TextInput
      placeholder='Enter Password'
      returnKeyType="next"
      secureTextEntry={true}
  />
</View>
```

I believe this is not a bug and is made by design

Answer (score 0):

On my side I was using `keyboardType="phone-pad"`, so when I change it to `keyboardType="numeric"`, I was able to fix the issue, I hope this solution can help anyone facing a similar problem.

have a good code! :D